# how to cut & paste and duplicate images

Tags: images, duplicate

With the help of this forum I have managed to name my images with Exiftool by their unique date and time. My problem is that I have dozens of folders with hundreds of images in each folder combined with numerous duplicate images.
Often some folders are almost copies of other folders.
I have tried cut & paste which then mentions about overwriting the original or not - I keep the larger image..
Perhaps there is a command line which would cut and paste and if there is a duplicate only overwrite the existing image if the new one is larger.
I do not understand why but I seems to have lots of duplicate images - some at eg 2.1 Mib and then another copy at 2.0 Mib.
Thank you for any advice

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `fdupes`…

https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I did not think fdupes was able to decide to save the larger file - I assumed it would just save the first file it found -

Comment: It, actually, looks at the file contents and if they're identical, deletes one. More info is available at the link.

Comment: I'll go through the info -